# cakephp rest delete missing template error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a REST delete action in my controller that simply looks like:

```
$asset = $this->Assets->get($id);
if ($this->Assets->delete($asset)) {
    $this->response->statusCode(204);
}
```

In controller initialize i've done

```
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

However for some reason, despite being REST API, I getting the error `"Template file \"Assets/json/delete.ctp\" is missing.",`

Cake book suggests the `response->statusCode` is all that is needed, why is it trying to get a template for view ?

(v3)

Comment: `Cake book suggests` - please link to the page you're reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Return the response object

Setting the status code is not itself enough; all that does is, well, set the status code on the response object. The code would then still go through the [normal render process](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L119-L123):

```
// Dispatcher code
$response = $controller->invokeAction();
...
if (!$response && $controller->autoRender) {
    $response = $controller->render(); // Code execution reaches here
...
```

To have the dispatching process bypass normal view rendering, return the response object:

```
function foo() 
{
    $this->response->setStatusCode(204);
    return $this->response;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but there is no output whatsoever ?  I need it to at least return an "OK" type status

Comment: Are you aware that a http 204 must have no body?